# Use MacBook to Control Mac mini (where Mac mini is not connected to network)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-mini

I am traveling with my MacBook and my Mac mini. I have no external display, mouse, or keyboard.

I know that I can use an ethernet cable or screen sharing to have control over my Mac mini, *if* the Mac mini is already connected to the same network. But since I just arrived to my new environment, that is not the case.

Is there a way to somehow use my MacBook as a display/keyboard/touchpad for my Mac mini?

In case it's not clear, I have a:

- M1 Mac mini (not connected to network)
- MacBook Pro 2019 (connected to network)
- USB C / Thunderbolt cable to connect the two together

Just to reiterate once again, **the Mac mini is not connected to the network and a remote screen sharing has not been configured yet.**  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like Catch 22 to me. Can't reach it until you configure it & you can't configure it because you can't reach it. You need the BYO keyboard, mouse & display… and you will need it network connected even after that to remote to it using Screen Sharing.

Comment: If it's not configured, at the very least you will need a cheap capture card, an HDMI cable (bonus if it's HDMI to USB C in which case you won't need an additional dongle), as well as a wired (or USB) keyboard/mouse combo. With this you can view the screen and configure everything you need to. This combination will run you about $30-40 on Amazon

Comment: so there's no way to simply use my MacBook as a keyboard&mouse&display?

Comment: Not to set the mini up. First you need K, M, & D physically connected. Then once set up, you connect the mini to the same LAN as your MBP [or wire them directly together with an ethernet cable] & you can remote to it, using your MBP as K, M, & D.

Comment: okay... so i need to acquire k/m/d either way it seems, at which point i will no longer need my mbp to control my mini! too bad. thanks for the help!